# Split Column containing 2 values into different column in pandas df

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
bigram         frequency
(123,3245)       2
(676,35346)      84
(93,32)          9
```

and so on, till 50 rows.

what i am looking for is, split the **bigram** column into two different columns removing the brackets and comma like,

```
col1     col2      frequency
123       3245        2
676       35346       84
93        32          9
```

is there any way to split if after comma,and removing brackets.

Comment: What are in the bigram column? are they tuples or they are strings of tuple format? Check `type(df.bigram.iloc[0])`

Comment: @Psidom type is **tuple**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `bigram` column happens to be string format, you can use `.str.extract()` method with regex to extract numbers from it:

```
pd.concat([df.bigram.str.extract('(?P<col1>\d+),(?P<col2>\d+)'), df.frequency], axis = 1)
```

[image]

Or if the `bigram` column is of tuple type:

*Method1*: use pd.Series to create columns from the tuple:

```
pd.concat([df.bigram.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, index=['col1', 'col2'])), 
           df.frequency], axis=1)
```

*Method2*: use `.str` to get the first and second element from the tuple

```
df['col1'], df['col2'] = df.bigram.str[0], df.bigram.str[1]
df = df.drop('bigram', axis=1)
```

Comment: Sir, your method2's result gives me 4 columns, my previous two columns `Bigram   Frequency   col1    col2`. i'e on the right of frequency but i want only `col1  col2  frequency`

Comment: You can drop the `bigram` column with `df = df.drop('bigram', axis=1)`. see the update.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a new column for each pair of the tuple.

```
df['col1'] = df['bigram'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['col2'] = df['bigram'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

---

To create a data frame with ONLY `col1`, `col2`, and `frequency` where the order is important, it is easier to create a new data frame altogether and populate it.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
df_new['col1'] = df['bigram'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df_new['col2'] = df['bigram'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df_new['frequency'] = df['frequency']
```

Comment: Sir, your result gives me 4 columns, my previous two columns `Bigram   Frequency   col1    col2`. i'e on the right of frequency but i want only `col1  col2  frequency`

Comment: Ah.  You want **ONLY** col1, col2, and frequency, and the order is important?

Answer (score 2):

very close to @Psidom's answer.
I use `pd.DataFrame(df.bigram.values.tolist(), columns=['c1', 'c2'])` instead of `df.bigram.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, index=['col1', 'col2']))`

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.bigram.values.tolist(), columns=['c1', 'c2']),
           df.drop('bigram', 1)],
          axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: sir i am getting an error while running your code. `labels ['Bigram'] not contained in axis`

Comment: yes sir, but i made the respective changes from bigram to Bigram while running your code